# Can $\mathbb{R}[[X]]$ as the ring of one-sided sequences be extended to a field of two-sided sequences with termwise addition?

Tags: field-theory, formal-power-series, polynomial-rings

We can interpret $\mathbb{R}[[X]]$ as the set of one sided sequences 
 by interpreting $(a_0,a_1,\dots)$ as $a_0x^0+a_1x^1+\dots=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$.

Can we extend this to a field of two-sided sequences $(\dots,a_{-2},a_{-1},a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$ while preserving the ring structure of one-sided sequences and having termwise addition?  That is: I want

$$(\dots,a_{-2},a_{-1},a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)+(\dots,b_{-2},b_{-1},b_0,b_1,b_2,\dots)=(\dots,a_{-2}+b_{-2},a_{-1}+b_{-2},a_0+b_0,a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,\dots)$$

and, if $a_i=0$ for all $i<0$, then I want the multiplication to be defined as in the formal power series ring.

Remarks: If one does not care about including all two-sided sequences, we can take the Laurant series.

If we want to include all two-sided sequences but we don't care about termwise addition, even if we want to preserve the ring structure where all terms with negative indices are 0, this is easy by finding a bijection from two-sided sequences to one-sided sequences sending any element that is already a one-sided sequence (i.e. all terms with negative indices are 0) to itself, and sending the rest to other Laurant series (existence is given by Schroder Bernstein)

Similarly, if we care about termwise addition but not inverses, we can use the bijection sending $a_i$ to $a_{2i}$ if $i\ge0$, and $a_i$ to $a_{-2i-1}$ if $i<0$ and use polynomial/power series multiplication.

Comment: In your first paragraph, it seems you already want to have $\Bbb R[[X]]$, not $\Bbb R[X]$? -- I suppose you want $\Bbb R[[X,Y]]/(XY-1) $.

Comment: It seems your final sentence is an answer to your question.  Do you mean to have some condition about preserving "inverses"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, I think $\mathbb{R}[[X]]$ would fit  better there; with regards to your second sentence, should I interpret that as saying that any such field is an isomorphism to $\mathbb{R}[[X,Y]]/(XY-1)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey For it to be a field, I would need inverses to exist, but the ring of formal power series does not have inverses.

Comment: Ah, I missed the word "field".  I would suggest mentioning that in the body of your post and not just the title.

Comment: You can't multiply two formal series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n x^n$. The fraction field of $\mathbb{R}[[X]]$ is $\mathbb{R}[[X]][X^{-1}]$ so it has only finitely many non-zero coefficients on the left. What do you want more ? The two-sided formal series is only a $\mathbb{R}$ vector space and a $\mathbb{R}[X]$ module.

Comment: The series can't be infinite in the negative direction. With that constraint you get what's called the field of formal Laurent series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and you can additionally require the natural $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure to be preserved.  Consider the set $S$ of two-sided sequences as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ in the obvious way, with $\mathbb{R}[[X]]$ as a subspace.  Let $C\subset S$ be the subspace of sequences with $a_i=0$ for all $i\geq 0$, so $S=\mathbb{R}[[X]]\oplus C$.  Note that $C$ has dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Now let $F$ be any field extension of $\mathbb{R}((X))$ such that the $\mathbb{R}$-dimension of the vector space $F/\mathbb{R}[[X]]$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$.  (In fact, any nontrivial field extension of $\mathbb{R}((X))$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ will have this property.)  Let $D$ be a linear complement of $\mathbb{R}[[X]]$ inside $F$, so $F=\mathbb{R}[[X]]\oplus D$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.  Choose a vector space isomorphism $C\cong D$.  This then induces a vector space isomorphism $S=\mathbb{R}[[X]]\oplus C\cong \mathbb{R}[[X]]\oplus D=F$.  Transferring the field structure of $F$ along this isomorphism, we get the desired field structure on $S$.